# Why was this realism question marked as closed?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

Why was this... [Do US private schools ask Chinese students to get referral letters from the Chinese Consolidated Benevolent Association to join them?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/110002/do-us-private-schools-ask-chinese-students-to-get-referral-letters-from-the-chin)
 closed?